# Quectel EC20 LTE Module doesnt show me incoming call or sms

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem, lte, quectel

I'm using a LTE Module QUECTEL EC20 of this model connected to my Arduino as software Serial monitor and AT Commands directly, I can communicate perfectly with the Module, I get answer OK, Signal, IMEI, and a lot of commands with any problem.

[Quectel ec20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIi1j.jpg)

I have tone and I can answer the incoming call with ATA or hang up a call.

I'have tried changing the baud rate from 115200 to 19200 and 9600

I check all these commands:

```
AT+CLIP=1 
AT+CREG=1
AT+COPS?
```

Everything look perfect but I dont get incomming data in my serial when I call or send a sms.

I have experience with SIM800, SIM5320, SIM7600 of SIMCOM brand working perfectly, But this is my first time trying this model and I have a lot of 5, I tried with all.

I have like one week looking information and trying but without success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me understand, please. You are not able to receive data DURING a voice call? And what kind of data are you trying to exchange? What AT commands do you provide in order to perform this data exchange?

Comment: @Cubo78 Hi, yes for example when you call to the number in a Sim800 or sim5320 the serial trasmit the number and some extra data while the call is coming. Like this:

+CLIP: "2069220880" , "161" , "","",0

Comment: @Cubo78 that line of data is sent to the serial monitor for each telephone ringing. And the same way with a SMS normally it is sent to serial. But I dont know if I must activate some function in QUECTEL EC20 to start to receive this data.

Comment: @fabuktovic now it's clear. I'm not an EC20 expert, but I know AT commands standards and your procedure seems correct. `+CLIP=1` should actually enable incoming calls URCs. Just a question: do you reboot the device between `+CLIP=1` and the incoming call? Otherwise you might have found an EC20 bug :)

Comment: @Cubo78 thanks for your answer, really I've tried everything reboot, turn off, and also save configuration with AT&W and restart the configuration to factory values, it's very strange. I received 5 Quectel Ec20 and 5 Sim7600 of the same Aliexpress seller and the SIM7600 it's working perfectly.

Comment: I was just asking, because +CLIP value is saved in profiles and is not persistent to reboot, so that any reboot restore it to default velue (0, meaning no URCs). So it seems that you found a Quectel Easter egg.. :) (bug or unimplemented feature).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I had to contact to QUECTEL support and they responded very kindly and fast.

They suggest to add this at command to change the port of data delivery.

```
at+qurccfg="urcport","uart1"
```

after that! finally it start working perfectly. If any need extra help please contact me. Thanks